# EF Core + Sqlite 3.24.0 throws exception in trigger with UPSERT operation

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, ef-core-2.1

I'm using `EF Core 2.1` and my testing db is `Sqlite 3.24.0`.
In my database. There is one trigger which is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS OnTopicInsert
AFTER INSERT ON Topic 
WHEN Topic.Status == 1
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO CategorySummary(CategoryId, TotalPost, TotalFollower, LastTopicId, LastTopicTitle, LastTopicCreatedTime)
    VALUES(Topic.CategoryId, 1, 0, Topic.Id, Topic.Title, Topic.CreatedTime)
    ON CONFLICT(CategoryId) 
    DO UPDATE
    SET TotalPost = TotalPost + 1,
        LastTopicId = Topic.Id,
        LastTopicTitle = Topic.Title,
        LastTopicCreatedTime = Topic.CreatedTime;
END
```

What I want in the trigger is:

- When a **Topic** is created, **CategorySummary** will be inserted if does not exist and update if it does.

Without the trigger, my app was OK. After inserting that trigger into my `sqlite 3.24.0`. There is one exception thrown back:
**SQLite Error 11: 'malformed database schema (OnTopicInsert) - near "ON": syntax error'.**

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: Does the insert work outside of the trigger? Are you absolutely sure your app is using a sqlite library that is 3.24 or newer (what does `SELECT sqlite_version()` run in your app give you?) It sounds like you might be using an older one.

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` provider to connect to my sqlite database. By reading its document, the provider supports sqlite version 3.7 and above

Comment: What version of the **sqlite** library is it using? That's the one that matters. Log or otherwise display the version string returned by the above query when executed in the app to find out for sure.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. 
I tried to run that command using `EF Core 2.1`, and the version was `3.22.0`.
How can I update the lib to the latest one ?

Comment: I don't have a clue; someone else might.

Comment: I have been searching for tutorial of `EF Core` and `Sqlite`. They always talk about installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`, and I already installed the latest version. It is weird.

Comment: Try installing the latest version of the `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` NuGet package.

Comment: Still `3.22.0` :|